# Se puede compartir una imagen desde un ImageView sin guardar la imagen?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un código que genera un QR en un ImageView quisiera compartir ese QR pero sin tener que guardar la imagen en el dispositivo.

```
public void comparteQR (){
    datoQR.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = datoQR.getDrawingCache();
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "title", null);
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "select"));
}
```

Comment: ¿Compartirla con quién y por qué medio? La pregunta no es clara.

Comment: en el apartado de compartir de android te da varias opciones puede ser algun aplicativo o por bluetooht incluso imprimir

Comment: Ok, y ¿cuál es el problema con tu código exactamente?

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es que pueda compartir el QR que genero en el imagenview pero sin tener que guardar la imagen en el dispositivo pero mi código si guarda la imagen quiero saber como evitar que guarde o si es posible

Comment: El código hace lo que le estás diciendo que haga, en este caso, guardar la imagen en Media Store. Si quieres otra cosa: enviarla por email, dar la posibilidad de compartirla, etc, pues escribe un código que haga eso que quieres, lo cual aún no queda claro qué es. [Quizá esto](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send) puede ayudarte a clarificar tu problema.

Comment: ok revisare el código gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si generas una imagen en memoria es requerimiento guardes el archivo para poder enviarlo, ya que es necesaria la URI para que el sistema operativo sepa que archivo deberá enviar:

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, uriImage);
```

Como otra opción puedes usar `Glide`, que en realidad también guarda la imagen en caché y envía la imagen, revisa este [ejemplo de @ashad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52950687/250260) :

```
 Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(imagelink)   \\link of your image file (url)
                    .asBitmap().skipMemoryCache(true).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)

                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(250, 250) {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {


                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey view/download this image");
                            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), resource, "", null);


                            Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);



                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
                            intent.setType("image/*");

                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via..."));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadStarted(Drawable placeholder) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            super.onLoadStarted(placeholder);
                        }
});
```